# How to upload pdf or docx file to server through fetch?

Tags: react-native, pdf, docx

I have a problem, how can I fix it to post a file with some data to the server:

```
Object {
  "errors": Object {
    "file._parts": Array [
      "The file._parts must be a file of type:  pdf,  docx,  application/pdf,  text/pdf,  doc,  zip.",
    ],
  },
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
}
```

download through button

```
    let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});
    alert(result.uri);
    this.setState(this.state.file = result);
    console.log(this.state.file)
```

There Code of fetch
I`m not sure but there problem with file then i must use library that will save pdf file as pdf file but i dont imagine how to do it and when I google it there was no answers related to it

```
async createCV(){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.state.file.uri);

    try{
            let response= await fetch('mypath', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.state.token.accessToken,
            }, 
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: this.state.nameCan + ' ' + this.state.surename,
                location: this.state.location,
                dob: '01-01-1999',
                experience: this.state.experience,
                email: this.state.email,
                phone: this.state.phone,
                citizenship: 'Kazakhstan',
                vacancy_id: 6,
                file: this.state.file,
                job_title: 'IOS',
                sex: 'm'
            })
        });
        let res = await response.json();
        console.log(res)
        if (res.name){
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Vacancy')
        }
        else{
            alert(res.message)
        }
    }
    catch(errors){
        console.log("No connection")
    }
}
```

Comment: Plz add you sending code

Comment: @gran33 please see it